# Vertically centered element when zooming

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zooming

I want my element to be vertically in the middle of the body (viewport). The problem is when zooming a page, my element is cutoff (just a part is visible). There is no scrollbar.

Since I use Vite React, I decided to set "height:100%" on the: html, body, div (id="root") & main.
This works well until zooming. What I want to achieve is to have this element centered even after zoom (or at least not to be cutoff). Can centering be achieved using padding or some another method? It confused me.
p.s. I used Tailwindcss and "d" indicate my custom desktop breakpoint.

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <main className=" h-full flex flex-col d:justify-center d:items-center">
      <article>
        <header>
        ...
        </header>
      </article>
    </main>
  )
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <div id="root" class="h-full"></div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```